# Add any two numbers recursively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to add two numbers using recursion in JavaScript. So far I've come up with

```
function sum(x, y) {
    if (y != 0) {
      return sum(x + 1, y - 1);
    } else {
      return x;
    }
}
```

It works with all positive numbers, however, not for negative integers. I get a Max call stack size exceeded error.

I've searched for a simple recursive function in Js but have only found them in C and other languages I'm not too familiar. I've found one for Fibonacci and numbers in an Array, but I just want any two numbers, not an array.

Comment: Why would you use recursion to add two numbers?

Comment: What is the point of this code?  Is this some sort of odd homework assignment?  Because there's certainly no reason to add two numbers this way in the real world.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a function **dim(n)** either in C or JavaScript, possibly a JavaScript Closure, where diminish(5)  gives 4 , diminish(-5) gives -4 and diminish(0) gives 0.  Something like Dirac's ladder operators. Its inverse would be **div(n)** divergence of n which takes n 1 further away from zero.( div(0) returns 0 )  Useful for bigger recursive functions if nothing else; a generalisation of ++ and --.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle other cases like this.

```
function sum(x, y) {
  if (x == 0)
    return y;
else if (y == 0)
    return x;
else if (y > 0) 
    return sum(x + 1, y - 1);
else
    return sum(x - 1, y + 1);
}
```

Comment: Note that your last two cases are the same, you so can combine them into a single `else`.  Also `(y != 0 && y > 0) ` is redundant; it can be expressed simply as `(y > 0)`.   Moreover you're first case is already covered by the others.  Together, those should all simplify this a good deal: `const sum = (x, y) => (y == 0) ? x : y > 0 ? sum (x + 1, y - 1) : sum (x - 1, y + 1)`.

Comment: yes Scott Sauyet

Comment: You can always [edit] your answer with updates.  It's considered good form to include more than code.  Some explanatory text would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is, presumably, homework, let me just give a hint instead of spoon-feeding you the code:

Instead of simply checking for `y != 0`, try checking for `y < 0` and `y > 0`.  You should be able to figure out how to handle each of these two cases in such a way that you'll, eventually, arrive at `y == 0`.

---

Ps. Of course, even with the extension I suggested above, your method will still only work for integers.  If you really want to make it work for arbitrary floats, perhaps the simplest solution would be something like:

```
if (y > 0 && y < 1) {
    return sum(2*x, 2*y) / 2;
}
```

The reason this trick works at all is that JavaScript floats are binary, and thus can only exactly represent numbers of the form *n* / 2<sup>*k*</sup>, where *n* and *k* are integers.  Thus, repeatedly multiplying any (finite) number by 2 in JavaScript will eventually yield an integer.

Of course, it seems kind of silly to use multiplication and division in order to implement addition, but at least we could, in principle, replace them with simple bit shifts — that is, we could, if bit shifts worked on floats in JavaScript, which, alas, they don't.

Comment: I have a feeling that the version for floats may get a stack overflow, because doubling the fraction will rarely hit an integer exactly, it will usually produce `1.x`, then you'll subtract to `.x`, then you'll double a few times to get `1.y`, and so on. It will take many repetitions before the fraction disappears entirely.

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, it'll take at most 1074 doublings, since 1 / 2^1074 is the smallest positive number an [IEEE 754 double-precision float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can store. That should be well within the recursion limit. (It is, however, quite easy to get a "too much recursion" error by using that OP's code for large integers; on my Firefox dev console, it works up to `sum(0, 3071)` but fails for any larger values of `y`.)

Comment: For small values of large :)

Comment: But it's not just doublings. After it doubles a few times to get back over `1`, it has to subtract `1` again and start doubling again. `.6 -> 1.2 -> .2 -> .4 -> .8 -> 1.6 -> .6`. And if it weren't for floating point inaccuracy, that would be an infinite loop since we got back to our starting number.

Comment: @Barmar: Indeed, the "floating point inaccuracy" is exactly why it works: the number "0.6" is actually represented as a float by a finite string of binary digits whose value is close to, but not exactly, six tenths. Multiplying this representation by 2 enough times (in fact, 53 times is enough for *any* float above 0.5) will yield an integer.

Comment: But you're not going to multiply 53 times in a row. When you get 1.2 (plus epsilon) you'll go back to the subtraction branch of the `if`.

Comment: @Barmar: Subtracting 1 from a number will not change its fractional part.  But honestly, at this point I'd suggest just trying it yourself (and maybe printing out the intermediate values in binary using `.toString(2)`). If you still don't see why it works, you might consider asking a question about it here on SO.

Comment: You're right. I tried `sum(10.9999999999, 20.999999999)` and it only required 110 recursion steps.

Answer (score 1):

If the y value is initially negative  the recursion wouldn't  stop because of your conditional statement. Why not have an if statement that checks if the y Val is greater or less than 0. Then you can decrement y if y is greater than 0 or increment if y is less than 0(to obtain the same effect you would need to decrement x in the case of y <0). Thus the recursion would stop.